# I am trying to print x square with python, I do not want 'x2'

Tags: python

I am trying to make a calculator with python. I will like to print x square correctly, but mine still print this: x2. How can I print it  with 2 on top of x with python if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the code you have written so far. It's difficult to suggest where you might have gone wrong if you don't show what you have done.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Have you tried using the `²` character? Surely you cant have expected `x2` to show up as `x²`?

Comment: I tried to use  : # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on top of my .py  for special characters, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

To square an integer in python, use two asterisks e.g. `2**2` will produce `4`

For example, save this as `square.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
integer_to_square = int(sys.argv[1])
print(integer_to_square**2)
```

Then run it with different inputs

```py
$ python square.py 2
4
$ python square.py 4 
16
$ python square.py 8
64
$ python square.py 16
256
```